# Prototype Method is not a Function in some cases... Why?

Tags: javascript, recursion, linked-list, prototype, hoisting

Fairly new to linked list so I was trying to develop a method that would remove a node from the list. Then I would run that method within a function recusivley (or with a loop) until all the nodes of a  certain value were removed. The problem is when I try and run the loop an error saying the prototype method is not a function is thrown. Here's my code:

Linked list are made from this:

```
  function ListNode(x) {
    this.value = x;
    this.next = null;
  }
```

Method:

```
ListNode.prototype.remove = function (val) {
  var origin = this;
  var current = this;

  //check head
  if (current.value === val) {
    if (current.next){
      origin = current.next
    }else{
      return [];
    }
  }else{
    //check between head and tail

    var previous = current;
    while(current.next){
      if (current.value === val){
        previous.next = current.next;
        return origin;
      }
      previous = current;
      current = current.next;
    }

    //check last
    if (current.value === val){
      previous.next = null;
    }
  }
  return origin;
}
```

And function to remove all nodes of value k:

```
function removeKFromList(l, k) {

  if (l) {
    var a = l.remove(k) //this alone doesn't throw the error
    while (a != l) {
      l = a;
      a = l.remove(k); //this with the while loop throws an error
      //if the line above were removed function would run without error
    }
  }
  return l;
}
```

I know the problem stems from the line within the while loop:

a = l.remove(k)

because without it the function runs fine. I can change the while loop so the function runs recursively like this:

```
...
if (l != a){
  l = removeKfromList(a, k)
}
...
```

and still and error is thrown.

My question is why does that throw and error? More specifically, why isn't an error thrown when a is set to l.remove(k) in the first place? Why does the while loop/recursion thrown the error? (the error thrown is specifically "l.remove() is now a function").

Also if anybody has a better way of doing what I'm attempting I'm always up for learning something new.

Comment: Before the while loop `previous` is the same as `current`. Current needs to be changed to `current.next` and the predicate would just check if that is truthy.

Comment: Also `a` might be `null` or `[] ` and it does not have the method.